# 2D animation rig

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, 2d

I’m doing a very basic 2D cut out animation with a simple rig attached to it. But the bones are sticking to my planes in irrational ways (for example the head bone seems to move other planes besides the head). What is it that I’m doing wrong? I’m on Blender 2.78. I'm attaching the blend file

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix.

Have you ever heard of weight painting? If you haven't, search it up.

That is what is wrong with your model.

For each plane you will need to one by one repaint the bone weights. Painfully slow, but simple all together.

If you go into wireframe mode whilst doing this you will ensure you dont miss anything.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Comment: Ok. I'd realized I could do what I wanted by using "set parent to bone". I'm not quite sure I understand the advantage of weight painting. What does it do?

Comment: It allows you to move individual vertices by bones with varying influences. It's vital with 3d rigging to create realistic animations.

Comment: Ok. But this is 2D so I guess parenting to bone will do for now. But thanks anyway.